# 2sls second stage statistically insignificant

Tags: statistical-significance, 2sls

i conducted a two stage least square regression. The coefficients of my first stage are statistically significant, but my second stage is not. How can i interpretate this? My F-Statistic of the second stage is 17, so my Instrument is not weak.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It may simply mean that there is no relationship between the variables you are instrumenting and the dependent variable, at least not a statistically significant one.